# Can the CUDA RHEL repo be used with CentOS 8?

Tags: centos, rhel, nvidia

I'm using CentOS 8 (build 1905) on some machine, and would like to install [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) on it. It seems that other than a manual RPM download, there is also a YUM repository - for RedHat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 8, not CentOS 8: [this one](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/rhel8/x86_64/cuda-rhel8.repo).

Can I safely use it as a repo for my CentOS installation? Use it, but with certain caveats/snags? Or - not use it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cuda-rhel7 repo on the NVidia developer site is the correct one to use for CentOS 7, so the one from your link for would be correct for CentOS 8. It should be safe to use as normal.

You can also download the .run file installer from nvidia, but you will need to manually disable the nouveau driver and handle driver upgrades yourself.